# Proof of a $\log_i(z)$ formula

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

#### Context

While doing some calculations of $\log_i(z)$, I noticed a kind of "pattern" in the exact results, so I wanted to prove the following statement:
$$\forall z=a+ib, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, \log_i(z)=\frac{-2i\ln|z|+2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}$$ 
It seems that there is not much material on complex-base logarithms online, so I have not been able to find a lot of informations on this subject, especially about this formula. Such a shame in my opinion, because complex-base logarithms appears to be very interesting.

#### Proof

Here is my proof. I would like to know if it is mathematically correct, then if there is a shorter way to do it.

$$\frac{-2i\ln|z|+2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi} \\
= \frac{-2i\ln|z|}{\pi}+\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi} \\
= \frac{-2i\ln|z|\times \frac{\pi}{2}i}{\pi\times \frac{\pi}{2}i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi} \\
= \frac{\pi\ln|z|}{\frac{\pi^2}{2}i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi} \\
= \frac{\ln|z|}{\frac{\pi}{2}i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi} \\
= \frac{\ln|z|}{\ln i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}$$

We know that $i^{\log_i(z)}=z$, so we should calculate $i^{\frac{\ln|z|}{\ln i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}}$.
$$i^{\frac{\ln|z|}{\ln i} +\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}} \\
= i^{\frac{\ln|z|}{\ln i}}i^{\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}} \\
= (i^{\frac{1}{\ln i}})^{\ln|z|}i^{\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}} \\
= e^{\ln |z|}i^{\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}} \\
= |z|i^{\frac{2(\arg z+2k\pi)}{\pi}} \\
= |z|i^{\frac{2\arg z+4k\pi}{\pi}} \\
= |z|(i^{\frac{2\arg z}{\pi}}i^{\frac{4k\pi}{\pi}}) \\
= |z|(i^{\frac{2\arg z}{\pi}}i^{4k}) \\
= |z|(i^{2\frac{\arg z}{\pi}}\times 1) \\
= |z|(i^{2})^{\frac{\arg z}{\pi}} \\
= |z|(e^{i\pi})^{\frac{\arg z}{\pi}} \\
= |z|e^{i\pi\frac{\arg z}{\pi}} \\
= |z|e^{i\arg z} \\
= z$$

Am I right? Is there any shorter proof of this? Are there much better formulas for determining $\log_i(z)$, besides $\frac{\ln z}{\ln i}$?

Comment: You may write $\ln(a^2+b^2)=2\ln|z|$

Comment: @TymaGaidash You are right. It is more elegant and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logarithm to base $b\ne 1$ should be defined by $\log_b(z)=\log(z)/\log(b)$ where the logarithms on the right are natural logarithms. Then, we get

$$\log(i)=i\pi/2$$
$$\implies \log_i(z)=-2i\log(z)/\pi$$

Write $z=|z|e^{i\textrm{arg}(z)}$ so that
$$\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\textrm{arg}(z)$$
Combining these we get

$$\log_i(z)=\frac{-2i\log(|z|)+2\textrm{arg}(z)}{\pi}$$

if you chose another branch of the logarithm, you get the added $2k\pi$.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer and more effective this way. That's what I was looking for.